# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier when typing [−1, −2, 0, 1, 2] in IDLE 3.6.8 on Centos 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python using the Python 3.6.8 Shell on Centos 7.

When I type `[−1, −2, 0, 1, 2]`, I get this error:

> SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

with the cursor sitting on the character `1` after the `-` (minus sign).

Why am I getting this error?

If I remove the minus signs and type `[1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`, I do not get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are [en-dashes](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013) you're using. It's a subtle, but crucial, difference. The Python interpreter doesn't parse those as valid tokens.

```
[−1, −2, 0, 1, 2]
 ^   ^               sneaky en-dashes
```

Use normal hyphens/minus-signs instead.

```
[-1, -2, 0, 1, 2]
```

You can't find any en-dashes in the documentation for [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). Only hyphens are used.

> ```
> [...]
> augassign: ('+=' | '-=' | [...])
> [...]
> arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
> factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
> [...]
> ```

Comment: That's what I get for cutting and pasting from a PDF book. Thanks!